Suppose that $0\to A\xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is exact in an abelian category. Prove that $0\to A\xrightarrow{f} B\to Im(g)\to 0$ is exact
Suppose that $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is exact in an abelian category. I am trying to prove that $0 \to A\xrightarrow{f} B \to Im(g)\to 0$ is exact. Here, I use the definitiom that any $X \xrightarrow{h} Y \xrightarrow{k} Z$ is exact iff $Im(f) \cong \ker g$.
I have seen the short exact sequence $0 \to A\xrightarrow{g} B \to Im(f)\to 0$ countless times and I don't know why the original left exact sequences gives arise to that short exqct sequence. What is the map from $B$ to $Im(g)$? I know that the given sequence $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ is exact iff $(A, f)$ is (isomorphic to) the kernel of $g$, but I am not sure where this would be used.
Edit: The function $B \to \textrm{Im}(g)$ should be the morphism $\alpha \circ \textrm{coim}(g) : B \to \textrm{Im}(g)$ where $\alpha$ is the unique isomorphism from $\textrm{Coim}(g) \to \textrm{Im}(g)$.

I am pretty certain it's supposed to be $Im(g)$, not $Im(f)$.

@Arthur corrected, thank you

By definition of the kernel and coimage, for any arrow $g : B \to C$ we have a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathrm{ker}(g) \to B \to \mathrm{coim}(g) \to 0
$$
Using the isomorphism $\alpha : \mathrm{coim}(g) \to \mathrm{im}(g)$ in your statement, we can rewrite this as a short exact sequence
$$
\tag{1}
0 \to \mathrm{ker}(g) \to B \to \mathrm{im}(g) \to 0
$$
So if we have an exact sequence
$$
\tag{2}
0
\to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C
$$
then composing the first two arrows of sequence (2) with the last two arrows of the sequence (1), we get a sequence
$$
0
\to A \xrightarrow{f} B \to \mathrm{im}(g) \to 0
$$
This sequence is exact at $A$ by the hypothesis that (2) is exact and at $\mathrm{im}(g)$ by the exactness of (1), so it remains to show that it's exact at $B$.  Here we have
$$
\mathrm{im}(f) \cong \ker(g) \cong \ker(B \to \mathrm{im}(g))
$$
where the first isomophism holds by the hypothesis that (2) is exact and the second because (1) is exact.
